# Fritz 12 in Win 8.1

Tags: software

I am new here,  I am trying to find out if anyone knows if Fritz 12 can be installed in Win 8.1 OS,

Thank your for your help'

Answer (score 3):

Well, [these guys](http://www.amazon.com/forum/-/Tx1X8ZOOB8YBOX/ref=ask_ql_ql_al_hza?asin=B003B2MLDI) say it does.

[New in Chess](https://www.newinchess.com/Deep_Fritz_12-p-2462.html) gives the following system requirements.

System requirements: Minimum: Minimum: Pentium III 1 GHz, 512 MB RAM, Windows Vista, XP (Service Pack 3), DirectX9 graphics card with 256 MB RAM, DVD-ROM drive, Windows-Media Player 9, internet access (playchess.com, updates and activation).

Recommended: PC Intel Core 2 Quad, 2.4 GHz, 3 GB RAM, Windows Vista or Windows 7, DirectX10 graphics card (or compatible) with 512 MB RAM or more, 100% DirectX10 compatible, sound card, Windows Media Player11, DVD ROM drive and internet access (playchess.com, updates and activation).

Now I also have a question for you: Doesn't google work on Windows 8.1?